# how to make meteor ignore files in a Package?

Tags: meteor

I have a package which includes a file that gets frequently rebuilt. This causes meteor to restart each time that file is edited.

There are ways to get meteor to ignore files within the main app, eg putting inside a `.directory` but is there a way to do this within a package?

The catch is that I DO need the final file to be included for deployment, so it has to be named - as an asset - and included in the package addFiles.

The only solution I have so far is to host the asset external to the meteor app and load it in via http or something on each cold start, but that's a bit fragile.

Comment: one idea that comes to mind is to add some logic in your package.js that checks the environment (process.env.NODE_ENV), and only add the file in production.  maybe add a "static" version of the file in development

Comment: on second thought, since package.js is being run at build time, i don't think we can check process.env.NODE_ENV.  But you can specify packages as debugOnly or prodOnly, so maybe create two additional packages.  a debugOnly package that wraps your other package and adds the "static" file, and a prodOnly package that wraps your package and adds the final file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [Meteor v1.5.2.1](https://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html#v152120170926), there is support for a `.meteorignore` file. It behaves the same as a `.gitignore`. Have you tried using it?

You can use them in any directory of your project and are fully integrated with the file watching system.